# Is this the right way to split code with react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, code-splitting

Currently, I am building reusable table components and each column has its own functionality and I have to deal with a lot of components.

I am splitting every single piece of the component into a separate file and exporting it, but, by the end, I got about 25 files for rendering the table.

I am just wondering is it the right way for splitting the code and the components and make them reusable is by creating more and more files and small chunks? I am using TS.

Comment: better ask on a site like reddit

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer could differ people to people, But what I think to make our application scalable we make components only to reuse them for later, if you think at some point you will have to reuse the columns of your table somewhere else in the application you cannot right that logic again and again right? so that's where you can make the component only for the parts where you think you would need that component/logic again